# How to handle different types under one parent in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to React/Typescript and have run into a problem... I am trying to build a Google Forms clone.

My idea is to have an `interface` for each type of question, like so:

```
interface ShortText {
    question: string;
    placeholder: string;
}

interface MultipleChoice {
    question: string;
    placeholder: string;
    choices: string[];
}
```

And so on for each type. Next, I need to store a list of all these questions (belong to all different interfaces) in my store. **But, I can't do this because they all have different interfaces!**

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union Types could work here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types

For example using Discriminating Unions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

```
interface ShortText {
    kind: "shortText";
    question: string;
    placeholder: string;
}

interface MultipleChoice {
    kind: "multipleChoice";
    question: string;
    placeholder: string;
    choices: string[];
}

// Create a type which represents only one of the above types
// but you aren't sure which it is yet.
type Question =
  | ShortText
  | MultipleChoice;

...

let questions: Question[];

...

switch (question.kind) {
    case "shortText":
      ...
    case "multipleChoice":
      ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this is super helpful! What is the difference between type and interface and why did you use type for `Question` and interface for `ShortText` and `MultipleChoice`?

Comment: @RahulRentash `interface ShortText { ... }` is the clearer syntax for `type ShortText = { ... }`, and `type` can be used to create more complex types such as union types :)

Comment: Ahh, I see... one last thing: if I had a list of all the `kind`s (`const kinds: string[] = ["shortText", ...]`, how could I be sure that the `kind` is in that list? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, maybe you could define a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types)  `type QuestionKind = "shortText" | "multipleChoice"`